# Trying unsuccessfully to heat a 12 V 1 A jacket with an 18 V battery and 5 ohm potentiometer

Tags: power-supply

I"ve an electrical jacket that takes a 12 volt craftsman rechargeable battery.  If I hook it up to my power supply and set at 12 volts it works and draws 0.6 amps.   I am trying to get it to work with an 18 V rechargeable tool batter by using a potentiometer to dial down the voltage to 12 volts.  My voltmeter shows the output at the potentiometer at 12 volts but when I hook the wires to the jacket input the jacket does not turn on.  I measured the two wires going into the jacket with my voltmeter and it is 12 volts.  So I guess maybe I am not getting enough amps into the jacket or maybe too many?  But shouldn't the coat itself limit how many amps are going in based on the requirement?  I'm missing something here and any advice would be appreciated.  thank you.  -david

[image: CIRCUIT DIAGRAM]

OK.  Thanks for the advice.  I've added a circuit diagram.  I put the middle lead of the potentiometer directly into the positive side of the jacket leads and the negative to ground.  I tested the leads going into the jacket and i can get them to measure 12 volts by adjusting the potentiometer but the jacket still does not light up.  It is turned on so should if it had the right power.  when i test the jacket leads at 12 volts for Amps I get 10 microamps when the voltmeter dial is set to measure microamps and 1.6 Amps when the voltmeter is set to measure Amps (I don't understand the discrepancy here either).  In the diagram the one on the right will light the jacket up when hooked up directly to my power supply.  ( I also bought 10 LM782 voltage regulators on ebay for $5 bucks!)

Comment: Wiring diagram? resistance of potentiomenter?  Did you measure the voltage at the output of the pot with the jacket connected?

Comment: Could you link to the specific jacket you are using? It likely has active electronics for controlling temperature and shutting down when the battery voltage drops too low, instead of being just a plain resistor. If so, you need to provide it a stable and regulated 12v supply.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons why your approach is off: Loading Effects and Series Resistance in the battery itself. Both will throw off your calculations if you don't consider them.

By connecting the circuit to the device you load the battery down (current flows out of it). Previously with the potentiometer not connected to anything, current was flowing already, you can measure this with a multimeter if you don't believe me. By loading down the circuit even more current is required then, so you are getting an even bigger voltage drop on the potentiometer because more current is going through it now. The voltage that's left is what goes to your device.

The effect of the resistance within the battery will cause your voltage to be lower than expected when high currents are required in your circuit. These high currents must leave the battery and cause a voltage drop at the battery terminals. It's not as big of an issue as loading effects but it's something to be aware of.

Here is a more accurate model including these facts. (Ignore the resistor values)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foTVEf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You will also come to learn that a potentiometer is a bad design for dropping to a specific voltage! It's basically the reason you are experiencing loading effects in your circuit.

A better design would use a voltage regulator such as the LM7812.

However in the meantime, and perhaps the shortest answer to this question is: Tune the potentiometer output voltage to 12V while it's connected to the jacket.

Another fun thing that might happen is this voltage may drift as the wires in the jacket heat up and the effective resistance of the jacket changes. This is a discussion for another day.

Comment: wow.  thanks so much Sarrk.  so the resistance of the coat adds to the circuit total resistance so it no longer gets the 12 volts.  "However in the meantime, and perhaps the shortest answer to this question is: Tune the potentiometer output voltage to 12V while it's connected to the jacket..."  is an excellent straightforward workaround.  I'm going to study 'loading effects' more now that i am aware and will study and maybe try to buy a LM7812 so i can understand why this is a better solution.  thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question.  I was stuck.  -dave